# Why is describeConstable an optional?

Tags: java, java-12

Under what circumstance would `someEnum.describeConstable()` fail to return an `EnumDesc`?

i.e. it would return an empty `Optional`.

Comment: @JBNizet https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/constant/Constable.html

Answer (score 6):

`describeConstable()` is a method inherited from interface [`Constable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/constant/Constable.html), where the description is:

> Returns an `Optional` containing the nominal descriptor for this instance, if one can be constructed, or **an empty `Optional` if one cannot be constructed**.

Sure, in some classes, e.g. [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#describeConstable()), it can never be *empty*:

> Returns an `Optional` containing the nominal descriptor for this instance, which is **the instance itself**.

But the return value is an `Optional` because that is not true for all implementations of the interface.

The javadoc of [`Constable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/constant/Constable.html) has this to say:

> A Constable need not be able to (or may choose not to) describe all its instances in the form of a `ConstantDesc`; this method returns an `Optional` that can be empty to indicate that a nominal descriptor could not be created for an instance. (**For example, `MethodHandle` will produce nominal descriptors for direct method handles, but not necessarily those produced by method handle combinators.**)

Comment: Thanks for explaining what I'm looking at. I'm surprised the documentation for Enum does not include a more concrete description of its `describeConstable` implementation. That said, it is specified anywhere that `Enum` will never return an empty `Optional` here?

Comment: @WilliamEntriken [describeConstable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#describeConstable()): "*Returns an enum descriptor `EnumDesc` for this instance, if one can be constructed, or an empty `Optional` if one cannot be.*"- not very *specific*

Answer (score 5):

The method [`Optional<? extends ConstantDesc> describeConstable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/constant/Constable.html#describeConstable()) stems from the interface [`Constable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/constant/Constable.html), not from [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html). From [`Constable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/constant/Constable.html)'s documentation:

> ...
>
> The nominal form of an instance of a constable type is obtained via [`describeConstable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/constant/Constable.html#describeConstable()). **A [`Constable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/constant/Constable.html) need not be able to (or may choose not to) describe all its instances in the form of a [`ConstantDesc`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/constant/ConstantDesc.html)**; this method returns an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) that can be empty to indicate that a nominal descriptor could not be created for an instance. (For example, [`MethodHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) will produce nominal descriptors for direct method handles, but not necessarily those produced by method handle combinators.)
>
> ...
>
> See The Java™ Virtual Machine Specification:
>
> 4.4 The Constant Pool, 4.4.10 The CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic_info Structure
>
> ...